# Comic featuring an amalgamation of Edgar Allan Poe stories

Tags: story-identification, comics, edgar-allan-poe

I read this comic around 2010 or so, where a detective is tasked with solving a string of murders and disappearances happening around London. The comic was essentially an amalgamation of Edgar Allan Poe's short stories in an attempt to form a coherent narrative out of them. It took place in what seemed like the late 1800's. I believe it opened with one of the said murders, with a black figure cloaked in darkness. I most distinctly recall that the detective had a brother who was either the one to drag the main detective into the investigation, or was a police officer who didn't believe his brother was capable of solving the mystery. I seem to recall the detective having some sort of past connection to a case similar to this one.

Other details I can recall: Early investigations lead them to a clock maker, the detective being caught by some mysterious cult and trapped in a situation much like *[The Pit and the Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_and_the_Pendulum)* where he had to use rats to undo his ropes before escaping. I think a crow was a recurring image, but I don't remember if it spoke. One of the earlier murders was in a plaza where a clock tower chimed. I don't recall much else, other than it fit into a fairly light volume.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Ravenous-Dawn-Brown/dp/B003F8AOIM?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No, i think the setting was more late 1800's. Top hats, horse carriages, not really an action-oriented comic. I can't recall a muscled-up guy with his biceps exposed.

Edit, well looking up "ravenous comic" brings something entirely different lol. You might be right...

Comment: https://classiccomics.org/thread/6028/edgar-allan-poe might be good reading for suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any "fantastical elements" or "science fictional elements" in the question. Where are the topic police???

Comment: @user14111: You are right. I think I'm so used to thinking of the more fantastic aspects of Poe's works.

Comment: @Reeidly: Can you expound upon and fantasy/sci-fi aspects of the work? Is the killer more than human? Can they use magic? Does the protagonist find themselves travelling back in time to the scene of the crimes?

Comment: @Fuzzyboots I believe the serial killer was a part of a cult of some kind, and that there was a ghostly woman, though i can't recall if i'm mixing together other comics i read around that time. Sorry that i can't provide any more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found many details, but might it be Dawn Brown's *[Ravenous](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1177705.Ravenous)*?

[image: Front cover of Ravenous]

> "Something bad is happening in Good Fortune. A serial killer is ravaging this sleepy little town, leaving his victims sliced in two. A young detective races to piece together this puzzle before the killer can strike again." Inspired by the classic works of Edgar Allan Poe, writer, artist, and creator Dawn Brown presents Ravenous -- a new work that draws from the master while offering a startling new mystery of its own. Ravenous is a fully illustrated tale of suspense and mystery.

Comment: I can't view it on this computer due to the network, but it looks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adDe_vPqiuE might be a review/summary.

Comment: Unfortunately, this one seems to be in a more modern a setting than I remember. I don't think there were crop circles, either.